# From a nonlinear interactive IPython session to creating a script: Keep only code lines that contribute to final state

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, interactive

One of my IPython usecases is to figure out how to process (filter, etc.) large numpy arrays by interactively modifying and visualising them.
Once I'm happy with the result I want to create a script.

---

Therefore, **after an interactive session** it would be useful to **keep only the code which contributes to the final state** of some variables. This would **make the code more readable and reduce execution time**.

---

So I was wondering whether there exists a smart way to achieve this by for example filtering the IPython input history based on simple syntactic evaluation?

---

As a simple illustration, an interactive session containing

```
# play with a and b to create c

a = 2
b = someFunction(a,parameter = 1)
c = a + b # visualise c

b = someFunction(a,parameter = 2)
c = a + b # visualise c (happy now)
```

would be reduced to a script containing:

```
a = 2
b = someFunction(a,parameter = 2)
c = a + b
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the same thing, the only progress I have so far is to have a cell for utility functions, a cell for setting up the initial variables, and resisting the temptation to use one letter variable names.

Comment: For best results, you'd want to have a good way to classify whether numpy/scipy builtins are mutative and what they mutate. I don't think there's an easy way to do that, though. You'd also want to be able to analyze what arrays might alias each other; I'm not sure how hard that is. Alternatively, something that monitors your session as you work could detect what changes actually resulted from every operation and what arrays actually alias each other during the run, but there'd be a risk that different inputs could behave differently.

Comment: Also, don't forget, even if you filter your session down to things that actually contributed to the result, the result might still be an awful script. You'd still want to look it over and see where you used a bad tool because you didn't think of the appropriate one at the time, or where you computed something twice that didn't need to be recomputed, or things like that.

Comment: I agree that there might not be a straight forward and general solution, that's why I was wondering wether there are existing approaches out there